# Faster way of centering lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm looking for a better, faster way to center a couple of lists. Right now I have the following:

```
import random

m = range(2000)

sm = sorted(random.sample(range(100000), 16000))
si = random.sample(range(16005), 16000)

# Centered array.
smm = []

print sm
print si

for i in m:
    if i in sm:
        smm.append(si[sm.index(i)])
    else:
        smm.append(None)

print m
print smm
```

Which in effect creates a list (`m`) containing a range of random numbers to center against, another list (`sm`) from which `m` is centered against and a list of values (`si`) to append.

This sample runs fairly quickly, but when I run a larger task with much more variables performance slows to a standstill.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: `if i in sm:`  `sm` is a list: O(n) lookup. Start by creating a set or use bisection since the list is sorted. That _will_ speed things up.

Comment: Hi there,

I guess in essence it's a data centering task, where you have multiple arrays that need to be flattened into the same length (in this case, the length of ```m```) with ```null``` values imputed where the data is non-existent.

Comment: Would you mind providing some examples of what you want for smaller constants? Your code has a lot of hard-coded numbers and I'm not sure how I should change them to get a smaller sample. It doesn't help that I'm not really sure what any of the variables are.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I don't think it matters what sort of variables I've put in the above sample, the task is the same regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your mainloop contains this infamous line:

```
if i in sm:
```

it seems to be nothing but since `sm` is a result of `sorted` it is a `list`, hence `O(n)` lookup, which explains why it's slow with a big dataset.

Moreover you're using the even more infamous `si[sm.index(i)]`, which makes your algorithm `O(n**2)`.

Since you need the indexes, using a `set` is not so easy, and there's better to do:

Since `sm` is sorted, you could use `bisect` to find the index in `O(log(n))`, like this:

```
for i in m:
    j = bisect.bisect_left(sm,i)
    smm.append(si[j] if (j < len(sm) and sm[j]==i) else None)
```

small explanation: `bisect` gives you the insertion point of `i` in `sm`. It doesn't mean that the value is actually in the list so we have to check that (by checking if the returned value is within existing list range, and checking if the value at the returned index is the searched value), if so, append, else append `None`.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, I knew there was a way to do it without numpy!

Comment: yeah I love those optimization questions. `bisect` is not widely known but it rocks.